# .htaccess rewrite except images and script files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, match

I have the following rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk [NC,L,R=301]
```

But I only want it to happen if it is not a image file (.jpg, .gif, .png) or a script file (.js). Does anyone know how to set this?

(It is a wordpress blog and I want to redirect all pages but keep the scripts and images active.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.jpeg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.gif$
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.+)$ http://www.domain.co.uk [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and got an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to edit the .htaccess file located in the wordpress file to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/$ http://www.domain.co.uk

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```